# Nest can't resolve dependencies when I tried to use @Inject

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nest

I have tried to write npm module. Now I have two modules:

```
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { DATABASE_TYPE, GameSystemDBModuleFactory, IConfig } from './common';
import { GameSystemDBCacheModule } from './cache';
import { GameSystemDBService } from './game-system-db.service';


@Module({})
export class GameSystemDBModule {
  static register<T extends DATABASE_TYPE>(configs: IConfig<T>): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: GameSystemDBModule,
      imports: [
        GameSystemDBModuleFactory.createModule<T>(configs.databaseConfig),
        GameSystemDBCacheModule.register(configs.cacheConfig),
      ],
      providers: [
        GameSystemDBService,
        {
          provide: 'SESSION_CONFIG',
          useValue: configs.sessionConfig,
        },
      ],
      exports: [GameSystemDBService, 'SESSION_CONFIG'],
    };
  }
}
```

and

```
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  GAME_SYSTEM_DB_SERVICE_TOKEN,
  IPostgresConnectionConfig,
} from '../common';

import { PostgresGameSystemDBService } from './postgres-game-system-db.service';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { UserSessionModule } from './user-session';

@Module({})
export class PostgresGameSystemDBModule {
  static register(config: IPostgresConnectionConfig): DynamicModule {
    const providers = [
      {
        provide: GAME_SYSTEM_DB_SERVICE_TOKEN,
        useClass: PostgresGameSystemDBService,
      },
    ];
    return {
      module: PostgresGameSystemDBModule,
      imports: [SequelizeModule.forRoot(config), UserSessionModule],
      providers,
      exports: providers,
    };
  }
}
```

In service I try to use @Inject:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import { GameSystemDBCacheService } from '../cache';
import { SessionConfig } from 'lib/common/types/session-config.type';
import { UserSessionRepository } from './user-session';

@Injectable()
export class PostgresGameSystemDBService implements IGameSystemDBService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userSessionRepository: UserSessionRepository,
    private readonly gameSystemDBCacheService: GameSystemDBCacheService,
    @Inject('SESSION_CONFIG') private readonly sessionConfig: SessionConfig,
  ) {}
}
```

And I get an error:

```
[Nest] 16076  - 22.09.2023, 10:10:05   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PostgresGameSystemDBService (UserSessionRepository, GameSystemDBCacheService, ?). Please make sure that the argument SESSION_CONFIG at index [2] is available 
in the PostgresGameSystemDBModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is PostgresGameSystemDBModule a valid NestJS module?
- If SESSION_CONFIG is a provider, is it part of the current PostgresGameSystemDBModule?
- If SESSION_CONFIG is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within PostgresGameSystemDBModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing SESSION_CONFIG */ ]
  })
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

I tried to put SESSION_CONFIG to exports in GameSystemDBModule but I still have this error. In service PostgresGameSystemDBService I can get access to SESSION_CONFIG  properties.